# BAAS avoids eval code injection

Tags: javascript, node.js, eval

I create a private BAAS(backend as a service).

It can use eval() to execute different javascript code base on different task logic.

I tested the performance bewteen eval executing javascript string and native nodejs javascript code.
There is no significant performance difference between nodejs and eval(js).

my code:

```
var date1=new Date();   

//******************javascript code will be executed by eval()
var a=0;
var j=100000000;
for (var i=0; i<=j;i++){

    a=a+i*i*30+i/2+i/2;

}
console.log(a);
//******************

var date2=new Date();    
var date3=date2.getTime()-date1.getTime() ; 
console.log(date3);

console.log("--------------------------");

var date1a=new Date();

//******************javascript code executed by eval()
eval("var a=0; var j=100000000; for (var i=0; i<=j;i++){ a=a+i*i*30+i/2+i/2; } console.log(a);");
//******************


var date2a=new Date();  
var date3a=date2a.getTime()-date1a.getTime() ; 
console.log(date3a);
```

console displayes:

```
1.0000000150367534e+25
13339
--------------------------
1.0000000150367534e+25
13362
```

I put the eval string in another javascript file or database, the performance result are same.

As it is a private BAAS, the javascript string that eval() executes are safe.

But I wonder if those public BAAS(such as Parse.com) also use eval() to execute server side user cutomized javascript code.

if sure, is there a tool to detect the code injection such as

```
eval("rm -rf /etc/important-file;")
```

on eval()?

if not, is there other way to execute javascript code string of user/third party safely.

Your comment welcome